# Luhn's algorithm to check if a credit card is valid

Tags: c, cs50

I have scripted the Luhn's algorthm in C. I'm getting the results properly for the card type check. As in the Amex, Mastercard and Visa functions are correct. But I'm not getting the result for the Luhn's alorithm. Specifically for the check_sum function in the following code. What might be the issue here?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

long get_card_no(void);
int digit_count(long card_no);
int check_amex(long card_no, int noDigits);
int check_mastercard(long card_no, int noDigits);
int check_visa(long card_no, int noDigits);
int check_sum(long card_no, int noDigits);

int main(void)
{
    long card_no = get_card_no();
    int noDigits = digit_count(card_no);
    int amex = check_amex(card_no, noDigits);
    int mastercard = check_mastercard(card_no, noDigits);
    int visa = check_visa(card_no, noDigits);
    int checkSum = check_sum(card_no, noDigits);
    if (checkSum == 0)
    {
        if (amex)
        {
            printf("AMEX\n");
        }
        else if (mastercard)
        {
            printf("MASTERCARD\n");
        }
        else if (visa)
        {
            printf("VISA\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("INVALID\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }
}


long get_card_no(void)
{
    long n;
    do
    {
        n = get_long("Number: ");
    }
    while(n < 0);
    return n;
}

int digit_count(long card_no)
{
    int count = 0;
    while(card_no > 1)
    {
        card_no = card_no / 10;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int check_sum(long card_no, int noDigits)
{
    int digit1;
    int digit2;
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    int sum;
    for (int i = 1; i < noDigits; i += 2)
    {
        digit1 = (int)(card_no / pow(10, i)) % 10;
        digit1 *= 2;
        if (digit1 > 9)
        {
            digit1 = digit1 / 10 + digit1 % 10;
        }
        sum1 += digit1;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < noDigits; j += 2)
    {
        digit2 = (int)(card_no / pow(10, j)) % 10;
        sum2 += digit2;
    }
    sum = sum1 + sum2;
    return sum % 10;

}

int check_amex(long card_no, int noDigits)
{
    int first_digit = card_no / pow(10, (noDigits - 1));
    int second_digit = (int)(card_no / pow(10, (noDigits - 2))) % 10;
    if (noDigits == 15 && first_digit == 3 && (second_digit == 4 || second_digit == 7))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int check_mastercard(long card_no, int noDigits)
{
    int first_digit = card_no / pow(10, (noDigits - 1));
    int second_digit = (int)(card_no / pow(10, (noDigits - 2))) % 10;
    if (noDigits == 16 && first_digit == 5 && (second_digit == 1 || second_digit == 2 ||      second_digit == 3 || second_digit == 4 || second_digit == 5))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int check_visa(long card_no, int noDigits)
{
    int first_digit = card_no / pow(10, (noDigits - 1));
    if ((noDigits == 16 || noDigits == 13) && first_digit == 4)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Results for cs50/problems/2023/x/credit generated by check50 v3.3.8

```
:) credit.c exists
:) credit.c compiles
:) identifies 378282246310005 as AMEX
:) identifies 371449635398431 as AMEX
:) identifies 5555555555554444 as MASTERCARD
:) identifies 5105105105105100 as MASTERCARD
:( identifies 4111111111111111 as VISA
    expected "VISA\n", not "INVALID\n"
:) identifies 4012888888881881 as VISA
:( identifies 4222222222222 as VISA
    expected "VISA\n", not "INVALID\n"
:) identifies 1234567890 as INVALID
:) identifies 369421438430814 as INVALID
:) identifies 4062901840 as INVALID
:) identifies 5673598276138003 as INVALID
:) identifies 4111111111111113 as INVALID
:) identifies 4222222222223 as INVALID
```

these are the outputs I get for the test cases

Comment: Would you give an example input, what your code generates, and what you expect to see? You say you're getting an incorrect result, we don't know what that means.

Comment: Obligatory aside: CS50 teaches you to store credit card numbers as an *integer* (a `long`) which is fundamentally wrong. There are platforms where `long` will not be *large* enough to represent these numbers, and there is no requirement to perform arithmetic on the *entire* number with this algorithm - only its digits. Consider dismissing this part of the instructions, and storing and processing the credit card number as a *string*, as it  is both the correct thing to do, and greatly simplifies the exercise. The CS50 checker does not care how the results of your program are formed.

Comment: What might be the issue is treating the card "number" as an integer, and the use of `pow()` with integers, which can be inaccurate. If you input the card "number" as a string, there are the digits in a nice row for you to pick out (with ASCII adjustment). For example, the first digit (from the left) is `str[0] - '0'`, and the 3rd digit is `str[2] - '0'`.

Comment: using a char* for cardnumber can help to read digit by digit instead of using pow

Comment: @Oka "The CS50 checker does not care" --- not true.

Comment: @Oka Last time (the only one time) I tried, it unit-tested individual functions.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I have just double checked: `check50` (and `submit50`, both up to date), completely accepts an entirely `get_string` based solution for this problem.

Comment: @Oka Perhaps it varies with the assignment.

Answer (score 3):

Possible issues:

**32-bit `long`**

`long get_card_no(void)` may not exactly handle a 16 digit credit card number when `long` is 32-bit.  Use `long long` which is *at least* 64-bit.

**Digit count**

Certainly `while(card_no > 1)` should be `while(card_no > 0)`.

**Use integer math**

`double pow(10, x)` runs into trouble (inexact power 10 computation) when `x >= 16`.  Instead form a `long long pow10ll(x)` and just use integer math.

Recommend to not use floating point math anywhere for this integer problem.